# Footer isn't sticking to bottom though I have it coded

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

*I removed the footer for the time being, site had to go online. So the link is gone as well.*

As you can see (in FF2 as well as in IE7) the footer is at the bottom of the SCREEN, but not at the bottom of the page (content).

I have this in my code:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and this in the css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;  /* height of the footer */
}
#wrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px; 
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
}
*#wrap {            /* IE hack */
height:100%;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Or, making a long story short: I followed the instructions given [here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page).

Comment: your terms are confusing me: what *exactly* do you want? Can you offer a picture or a site link which does exactly what you want? Because otherwise this sample code is working as per fallen888's link

Comment: As I said in the comment of Fallen888's post, I tried that and it still doesn't work. I do want what is visible in his link though. As I explained below, there are issues with the footer floating halfway with longer pages.

Comment: but what do you mean by "halfway"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so with the #size inside the 100%, take the padding off the wrap and add the following to the #content

```
overflow:auto;
padding-bottom:30px;
```

then your link works for me in FF

Comment: It doesn't "float" halfway the page anymore... but now it's not at the bottom on shorter pages -.-   This is driving me nuts. I'll start all over again tonight. I'll rewrite the CSS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm accepting this, as it is closest to what I want :). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You did not follow your instructions carefully enough. The key to [Matthew's layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

is that container has position:relative while footer has position:absolute. That places one inside another. Notice that container has a space reserved for footer by reserving padding-bottom the size of footer. So, the layout only works when footer height is fixed.

Absolutely positioned with botttom:0 element will put itself at the bottom of closest relatively positioned parent. If none are there, viewport is used instead, and that is what's happening in your layout.

Your footer div is not a child of your wrap div.

Comment: That's because I have been editing it :$. I'm trying to fix it right now, in that code. I've put it back as I had it, footer inside wrap :)

Answer (score 3):

How about [this one](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: I have used this one as well and it most definitely works tested it on like 20 different major browsers, ranging from IE6 - FF3.

Comment: Could you maybe check my code below for mistakes then? Because I honestly tried this, without the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Move the padding from the bottom of the body to the bottom of the #wrap.  Your footer is always 30px from the bottom of the "page" because of that padding.  By putting it on the #wrap you'll prevent the contents of #wrap from going behind your footer.

Comment: That was my first idea as well :) But is gives the exact same problem, sticking to the bottom of the browser in stead of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px; 
    position: relative; 
}
*#wrap {            /* IE hack */
height:100%;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did, you left a few lines out. Sadly, for me it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the IE star hack causes the problem. Try changing the IE hacks with :

```
*html #wrap {
    ...
}
```

Comment: huh ? I copied all of your css and apply it to Matthew's layout, changed that line, and it all work as expected.

Comment: With a page that has more content than just the visible? Because the footer sticks to the bottom as long as I have less then 100% fill of content, and floats halfway when I have more content then "one screen full". I've removed the footer for the time being, so the example doesn't work anymore.

Comment: hmm.. weird. Works fine for me in FF3. What browser are you using ? It floats halfway when I changed those back to *#wrap.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else to this matter, every method described above all work on different sites, just not on mine.

This is my page source, non-relevant things are stripped (content and stuff):

```
<body>
    <div id="size"> javascript textsize modifier</div>
    <div id="wrap">

        <div id="top"> logoimage
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="menuwrapper">
                    <ul id="primary-nav">
                        <li> Homelink </li>
                        <li class="menuactive menuparent" class="over"> Link 2
                            <ul>
                                <li> Sublink 1 </li>
                                <!-- etcetera //-->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menuparent" class="over"> Active Link 3
                            <ul>
                                <li> Sublink 1</li>
                                <!-- etcetera //-->
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- end menuwrapper //-->
            </div> <!-- end menu //-->
        </div> <!-- end top //-->

        <div id="content">
            <div id="newssnippet"></div>
            <div id="roundedright"> <!-- rounded corners //-->
                <!-- 6 divs to create rounded corners //-->
                <div id="right">Random main content</div>
                <!-- 7 divs to create rounded corners //-->
            </div> <!-- end rounded corners //-->

            <div id="logo">Another logo</div>

            <div id="roundedleft"> <!-- rounded corners again //-->
                <!-- 6 divs to create rounded corners //-->
                <div id="left">News content</div> 
                <!-- 7 divs to create rounded corners //-->
            </div>  <!-- end rounded corners //-->
        </div> <!-- end content //-->

        <div id="footer"></div>

    </div><!-- end wrap //-->
</body>
```

Clearly, I am following the prescribed layout from the [link in the opening post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page).

Then in the CSS, I have:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
body {
    background: #e7e7e7 url(images/cms/background.jpg) repeat-x;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
#wrap {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px; 
    position: relative; 
    min-height:100%;
}
*html #wrap {     /* IE hack */
    height:100%;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: transparent url(images/cms/footer.png) no-repeat bottom center;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: .7em;
    text-align: center;
}
#footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

That should be every relevant bit...

What am I missing?

For the record: the footer is sticking to the bottom of the oage in the right position if the content is less than 100% high. So, if it doesn't fill the screen.
The footer is somewhere halfway the content if the content is more then 100% of the page, so when I have to scroll to see everyting.

Comment: As I said, the absolute element must be a child of the relative one. In your new html, "size" dive should be relative, not "wrap" div. Your "wrap" div does now wrap anything.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand... Footer is now inside Wrap, so it's their Child, right? Size is something else, and closed before Wrap even opens.

Comment: My fault, your indents confused me. Your layout actually works now - it positions footer at the bottom of the wrap, not at the bottom of the screen. You see overlap you do not like because you forgot to reserve the space for the footer. I edited my answer to address the issue.

Comment: But isn't this: padding-bottom: 30px; the space for the footer?

Comment: the wrap div is taking up 100% of the available height but then there's another div (#size) which consumes some height as well, i.e. more than 100% total, so your footer is going to be off position - are we missing some CSS?

Comment: Move padding-bottom from the body element, to the wrap element in your CSS.  Credit to @prestaul for getting that one earlier.

Comment: Oops. I wanted to delete my own comment, with a link in there, but instead I accidentally removed someone elses... Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good technic with demo in this site: http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/footerStickAlt/